# My Jenkins pipeline is getting success even if the job fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The stage which I pasted below is the issue. The curl command produces 401 bad credentails but the jenkins job is getting success. How can i make this job fail if the logins are not correct.

```
stage('Publish Puppet Module in Jfrog') {    
                steps {
                    script {
                        def metadata = readJSON file: 'metadata.json'
                        env.puppet_module_name = metadata["name"]
                        env.puppet_module_version = metadata["version"]
                        withCredentials([
                            usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'rt_ops_dev_user', passwordVariable: 'RT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'RT_USERNAME'),
                        ]) {
                            container('puppet') {
                                if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
                                    sh label: 'Deploy Puppet Module', script: 'curl -u${RT_USERNAME}:${RT_PASSWORD} -XPUT https://artifactory.test.io/artifactory/ops-puppet-prod-virtual/${puppet_module_name}.${puppet_module_version}.tar.gz -T pkg/${puppet_module_name}-${puppet_module_version}.tar.gz'
                                } else {
                                    sh label: 'Deploy Puppet Module', script: 'curl -u${RT_USERNAME}:${RT_PASSWORD} -XPUT https://artifactory.test.io/artifactory/ops-puppet-prod-virtual/${puppet_module_name}-${BRANCH_NAME}.${puppet_module_version}.tar.gz -T pkg/${puppet_module_name}-${puppet_module_version}.tar.gz'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }       
               }
            }
```

Jenkins Job Details:

```
+ curl -uops_dev_user:**** -XPUT https://artifactory.test.io/artifactory/ops-puppet-prod-virtual/test-puppet-poc.1.0.0.tar.gz -T pkg/test-1.0.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 10403  100    80  100 10323   1739   219k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  220k
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Bad credentials"
  } ]
}

[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: `curl` is likely returning a `0` exit code from the `sh` step method shell interpreter. Try using the `httpRequest` plugin for the REST API for more accurate results.

Comment: --fail did the trick.

> curl -uuser:token -XPUT --fail

Comment: Test use this command with `catchError`.